# I need to create a reset method for a binary search tree in java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So the goal is to reset or initialize the current position of the node for a given order type (ie. in-order, pre-order, post-order). We can assume there is at least one element in the tree, and we need to set the pointer to the relevant position based on the starting position of the order type. The function can only have the int orderType as its parameter.

This is what I came up with, my issue is I don't know if its right and I don't know how to test if its right.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    TreeNode root;
    TreeNode current;

    public class TreeNode {
        Comparable data;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;

        public TreeNode(Comparable data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }

    public static final int INORDER = 1;
    public static final int PREORDER = 2;
    public static final int POSTORDER = 3;

    public void reset(int orderType) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        switch (orderType) {
            case PREORDER:
                current = root;
                break;
            case INORDER:
                TreeNode node = root;
                while (node.left != null) {
                    node = node.left;
                }
                current = node;
                break;
            case POSTORDER:
                node = root;
                while (node.right != null) {
                    node = node.right;
                }
                current = node;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you could do this... After this is done, `current` will point to the node that will appear first in an X-order traversal. You cannot use it to implement such a traversal, so I fail to see the point of this exercise.

Comment: Those traversals are usually done recursively starting at root. Is this an attempt to implement an iterative traversal step-by step? In that case, your Node would need an additional `parent` link to be able to continue the traversal.

Comment: The point of this method is to initialize the pointer to the start of the traversal. I have an additional getNext method that obtains the item after this reset method put the pointer back in the beginning.

Comment: @teapot418 is correct that you need the parent link -- one of the problems with the code in your previous question, as I mentioned, was that you were not setting the parent link.

Comment: The premise doesn't make sense from a design perspective.  What you want is to create an `Iterator` that knows how to traverse the tree in the desired order, and store the "current" position there.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I'll say tho that's what the getNext method does. It doesn't seem necessary to have this reset method, but alas that's my task.